# How to use true or false data that comes from a bool statement?

Tags: c, arduino, boolean

so I'm creating a program which converts ASCII text to ASH or vice versa. The code below checks whether the text entered in normal character or ASH character. It then returns false if the character entered aren't char, at which point I want to run another function that converts ASH characters to char. If it returns true I want to run a function that converts char to ASH characters.

I have already created these functions but how do I act upon the true and false data of the bool statement. Like, if I want to use the fact that the statement has returned false, and make something happen based on that (ASHtoChar function), what would I do?

Thanks for any help!

```
   bool isASH(char * buf)
{
  for (int i=0; i<30; i++)
{
     if (buf[i] != '*' && buf[i] != '!' && buf[i] !='@') return false;
}
  return true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute code depending on whether `isASH` returned true of false, just do this:

```
if (isASH(&buf)) {
  // This is ASH
  ASHtoChar(...);
} else {
  // This is not ASH
}
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yeah thanks, would I need to put the if statement in another function to execute the result, for example I currently making a function that takes the users input:  void usinput(char * ib ){
  char inChar;
  for(int i = 0; inChar != ib[i]; i++){
     while(!Serial.available()) { 
    }

    inChar = Serial.read();
    ib[i] = inChar;
  }
}